# colab can't find weight files of YOLOv3

Tags: deep-learning, google-colaboratory, yolo

I want to use colab to train my yolo3 model,

I uploaded all yolo3 git files in my google drive,

then I mount google drive to colab,
after that I created a jupyter file and wrote these commands:

```
! python /content/drive/My\ Drive/Colab_Notebooks/yolo3/yolov3/train.py --data /content/drive/My\ Drive/Colab_Notebooks/yolo3/yolov3/data/captcha_data.data
```

but I got this error:

```
Namespace(accumulate=2, batch_size=32, bucket='', cache_images=False, cfg='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/yolo3/yolov3/cfg/yolov3-spp.cfg', data='/content/drive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/yolo3/yolov3/data/captcha_data.data', epochs=273, evolve=False, img_size=416, img_weights=False, multi_scale=False, nosave=False, notest=False, rect=False, resume=False, transfer=False)
Using CPU

data is  weights/darknet53.conv.74
Downloading https://pjreddie.com/media/files/darknet53.conv.74
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0     0    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0Warning: Failed to create the file weights/darknet53.conv.74: No such file or 
Warning: directory
  0  154M    0 16077    0     0  41542      0  1:05:11 --:--:--  1:05:11 41542
curl: (23) Failed writing body (0 != 16077)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/yolo3/yolov3/train.py", line 396, in <module>
    accumulate=opt.accumulate)
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/yolo3/yolov3/train.py", line 147, in train
    cutoff = load_darknet_weights(model, weights + 'darknet53.conv.74')
  File "/content/drive/My Drive/Colab_Notebooks/yolo3/yolov3/models.py", line 297, in load_darknet_weights

AssertionError: weights/darknet53.conv.74 missing, download from https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1uxgUBemJVw9wZsdpboYbzUN4bcRhsuAI
```

while there is  a folder called weights and inside it, is

> darknet53.conv.74

how should I fix that?

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to run this and download the weights from pjreddie:

`wget https://pjreddie.com/media/files/yolov3.weights`